# Is this code wrong or I'm not using it correctly?

Tags: excel, event-handling, vba

I was reviewing this piece of code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically what this is supposed to do is to copy the format of the cell above the one you are typing/pasting data so if you paste several cells it will start copying the format down to all the cells.

I've tested this code but most of the times I get an error '13 runtime the other thing is when it does work it only works for Column A, but for some reason the code is not stable its really flaky and take about 1.3 seconds for it to work. and it does not work when I paste the info into the cell just if I type it in which the actual purpose of the code is exactly that to force any type of data which is pasted to have the format of the cell above it

How can we make this code to copy/paste the format of the cell above the one I'm inputting data but to be applicable to all Columns not just Column A

Furthermore, is there a way to make the code run faster? If I delete anything I also get the Error '13. Also if I paste the code into an excel sheet which I already worked on it won't work at all.

Comment: whenever you use event handlers, it's probably a good idea to use the `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning of the procedure, (remember to set it back `True` at the end) in order to prevent infinite loop.  That may explain some of the lag you're experiencing.

Comment: I suspect the run-time error '13' is because of `Target.Offset(-1, 0)`. If the cell in Target is in the first row, an offset of -1 means row 0 which is an invalid row number. Also, the reason it works only in column A is because of the "if": `If Target.Column = 1`. The code will not do anything if the target column is anything other than 1, i.e. column A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mentioned the Event loop in the comment above, it's important to be mindful of that when using event handlers.

This line limits your code to Column A only, specifically the bit before the "And":

```
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
```

I'm going to make those changes here, but also limit it to exclude Row 1 (you'll get an error on `Target.Offset(-1,0)` if you you do that in row 1).

I am also going to limit it to only work on a target of a *single* cell.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Target.Cells.Count = 1 Or Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Of course it is possible to use the event handler on a range of cells, but then we would get an error on `Target.Offset(1,0)` (which is really asking for the `.Value` of that cell, which will fail if it is a range of multiple *cells*.).  Like I said, there's ways around it, but without actually knowing what you need, it's hard to make precise suggestion.

This might work; still limited to a single *row* but I think will work for multiple cells.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim nextRow as Variant

    If Not Target.Rows.Count = 1 Or Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub

    'store the next row in an array:
    nextRow = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Target.Offset(1, 0).Value)

    If Join(nextRow, "") = "" Then
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Basically I tried to create this ("Tried") because the excel workbook is filled with information copied from web pages, PDF documents and Word Documents, so the final users are not quite patient when they paste the information they want the info to be formated as the previous or the cell above the one they are pasting the info, I know format painter is the perfect solution for this how ever like I mentioned the Final users are not keen to take 2 seconds of their time to use it, so again I'm trying to find a way i guess you could say to "Force" the formating

Comment: Some one suggested this 
`ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats`

But I haven't tried that yet

Comment: I've tried what you wrote and its faster than mine (not really mine its a collaboration) but if I paste the information it does not copy the format

Comment: This only would work on a single cell i think.  I can try yo take a look at it a little later tonight. ..

Comment: The one you wrote worked for all the cells I tried but the only missing part is when I Copy/Paste the info into the cell

Comment: can you elaborate? This is working for me as long as I copy a *single* cell.

Comment: Yes you are right I don't know what happend but the first time I tried it did'nt work but I just tried it like 5 minutes ago and its working just fine if I paste or type the data the other only think is that if its more than one cell it wont do it you mentioned you limited the code to work like what would it look like without such limitation? would it Work?

Comment: Well right now you have a condition that *requires* only a single cell:  `If Target.Offset(1,0) = "" Then ...`  Here you're evaluating whether the next row is empty.  So the question to you is whether that logic needs to change: if you're copying multiple cells, is it sufficient to only examine the contents of *one* cell, or do you need to check each next row/cell?

Comment: i made a revision that I think will work for multiple cells within a row, but you would still only be able to paste one row of data at at a time.  Multiple rows of course is also possible...

Comment: Thank you David The multiple cell within a single row was just being fancy or me just naggin to much the code works perfect as it is I was just wondering if it was possible 2 thumbs up code works like a charm